# Backbone.Collection.fetch() always returns 404 while using jQuery.Mockjax to mock the resulting JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I have a simple setup that looks like this:

Main.js:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var Company = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
                  title: "",
                  description: ""
        },

        initialize: function() {
            console.log ("New Company Created");
        }
    });

    var Search = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/api/companies',
        model: Company
    })

    var s = new Search();

    s.fetch();
})(jQuery);
```

Mockjax.js

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '\/api\/companies',
    contentType: 'text/json',
    responseTime: 150,
    type: 'GET',
    response: function (settings) {
        "use strict";
        this.responseText = [];

        for ( var i=0; i<=100; i++) {
            this.responseText.push({ title: "Title " + i, description: "Description"})
        }

    }
})
```

This is what happens when I execute it:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/api/companies 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8526
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:63342/api/companies".
```

But if I do `$.get('/api/companies');` in the console, I get it correctly:

```
$.get('/api/companies');
MOCK GET: /api/companies 
Object {url: "/api/companies", type: "get", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true…}
 jquery.mockjax.js:546
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ways: http://japhr.blogspot.in/2011/10/overriding-url-and-fetch-in-backbonejs.html

I think it will help you

```
 var Appointments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model: Models.Appointment,
          initialize: function(options) {
            options || (options = {});
            this.date = options.date;
          },
          url: function () {
            return '/appointments/' + this.date;
          },
          setDate: function(date) {
            this.date = date;
            this.fetch();
          },
          parse: function(response) {
            return _(response.rows).map(function(row) { return row.value ;});
          }
        });
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

It was a jQuery.mockjax error, not Backbone. It was badly included in the wrong place in the HTML.